# Eventbrite API: What does event_list_attendees modified_after compare to?

Tags: eventbrite

I looked through the questions and found a question somewhat related but it wasn't the same.

If you use the `event_list_attendees` api call you get back a list of attendees. Those attendees have a `modified` field. One of the possible parameters in the api call is `modified_after`.

My question is regarding what triggers the `modified` field to update? Is this a user profile related field or is it related to this particular event ticket purchase? The api describes these two as the following:

> modified_after    Return only attendees whose “modified” value is equal
>   to or after this date/time (e.g., “2013-01-28 00:00:00″)
>
> modified  The date and time the event was last modified, in ISO 8601
>   format (e.g., “2007-12-31 23:59:59″).

Perhaps to explain why I am wondering what triggers `modified` to update. The goal is to create a small, one day use, mobile website that will allow users to see who has shown up so far for a local event I am working with. I know the api does not directly support this functionality. In my case however "close enough" is "good enough". If someone's ticket being scanned at the door triggers the modified field that would be sufficient.

So, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

The modified attribute relates only to the individual attendee in the order. So, it won't be triggered by the account wide profile changes for that respective user. However, if a user logs in to Eventbrite and changes the information that specifically relates to this event (example: they change the spelling on their last name for this specific order).

Alternatively, you can actually use /event_list_attendees and set "display_full_barcodes" to "true" to see the status of the barcodes. When the barcode is used, you'll know that someone has been scanned in.

If you come up with a cool hack, then we'd love to check it out!

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will try that when I get a chance. So, is it safe to assume "only_display": 'barcodes' doesn't default to "display_full_barcodes": "true"?

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic idea. It actually is "show_full_barcodes" not "display_full_barcodes". What values are possible for the status, checkin_type, and checkin_method fields? Primarily concerned about status as I mostly care if they checked in or not.